# Pass data from google map marker?

Tags: android, google-maps

How to pas dynamic data(Like usercode) from one activity to another by clicking on marker infowindow

```
for(int pin=0; pin<userData.size(); pin++)
          {
              BitmapDescriptor icon;
              if(  userData.get(pin).userloginSTS==1)
              {
                 icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.greenpin);
              }
              else
              {
                  icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.redpin);
              }

              LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(userData.get(pin).userlat,userData.get(pin).userlon);
              Marker storeMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
              .position(pinLocation )
              .icon(icon)
              .title(userData.get(pin).userName)
              .snippet(GetAddress(userData.get(pin).userlat, userData.get(pin).userlon))
              );
              storeMarker.showInfoWindow();

              final int usercod =userData.get(postion).userCode;
              mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {                          
                  @Override

                  public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {




                      Intent intent = new Intent(DataClass.this,test.class);
                      intent.putExtra("usercod", usercod);
                      startActivity(intent); 
                  }
              });

          }
```

on clicking on info widow it is sending last user value every time any solution please

Answer (score 2):

```
  googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {                          
                        @Override

                        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {

                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("mId",Data);
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setClass(ctx, YourClass.class);
                            intent.putExtra("mDetails", bundle);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: i have updated the code please review and give some solutions .. i am working with your code it is sending last usercode to next activity

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by last usercode? What are you trying to achieve? 
I mean you click on the InfoWindow and you move to the next activity. What data do you wish to send?